# IOS COREBLUETOOTH:convert characterstic.value

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, ascii, core-bluetooth

Doing corebluetooth app and able to read and write values when i am getting values in did update value for charactersticI can see that i have received proper response from peripheral as 01117100352e36302e313100000000e55a
     01 - 01-start byte
     11 - 17(Dec) - length of responce packet
     71 - response ID
      00 - Ignore this byte

```
   So now out of total length 17, first 4 bytes are header, last 2 bytes are CRC. We   
 need to read remaining 11 bytes and convert them to ASCII.
35 - 5
2e - .
36 - 6
30 - 0
2e - .
31 - 1
31 - 1
So Iam getting version number from watch as 5.60.11
```

i have tried with the "[IOS:Convert hex values from the characterstic.value result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645237/iosconvert-hex-values-from-the-characterstic-value-result/27645518#27645518)" link i am getting  the value as above but when applying same code  for010c5700010159105a105381  i need to get 100% and what i am getting in console is 00 .I had many values like that every value should be converted as above and show can any on help.

Comment: which byte or bytes in your hex string represents "100%"?

Comment: 010c5700010159105a105381 cointains 57 is response and 0000 is headers we can ignore and next 01-1,ignore59 next 10-0 and ignore 5a and next 10 -0 it give value of 100  i have shown as example above

Comment: That makes no sense.  The bytes I see are 01 0c 57 00 01 01 59 10 5a 10 53 81, so based on your previous question it is 01 - start byte, 0c - total length 12, 57 response, 00 - ignore and 5381 - CRC, which leaves 01 01 59 10 as the payload. You need to explain how any/some/all of these 4 bytes represent the battery level

Comment: sry for that i am new to iOS and CRC can u explain how to retrieve that data